# Vectorizing operations in nested loops: Python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, nested-loops, compiler-optimization

I have 2D numpy array, I need two nested loops to iterate over each of its elements. I want to make some vectorization on the nested loops, but I keep getting an error saying,

```
j= np.arange (0,x.shape [1])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

These are the original nested loops:

```
for k in range(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(A.shape[1]):
            A[k,j] = method1(x[k],x[j],a,c0,c1)
```

This is how I tried to make vectorization based on this answer, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/17702/python-numpy-running-15x-slower-than-matlab-am-i-using-numpy-effeciently,

```
j= np.arange (0, A.shape [1])
    for k in range(A.shape[0]):

            A[k,j] = method1(x[k],x[j],a,c0,c1)
```

I tried to change the indices in np.arange, but it didn't work.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this?

Thanks.

EDIT: By @ajcr comment, my mistake was in this line, j= np.arange (0,x.shape [1]), I was supposed to use the column count of the 2D array "A" as j= np.arange (0,A.shape [1]), but I have mistakenly used the 1D array x, hence the error. It's working perfectly now.

Comment: The `IndexError` for `x.shape[1]` implies `x` only has one dimension - are you sure it's 2D?

Comment: Oh! I really apologize for this mistake, I was supposed to have it as, j= np.arange (0,A.shape [1]). Thanks a lot for your comment, it's now working perfectly and much faster than before :)

Comment: I will edit my question and indicate the mistake.

Comment: If you post `method1` we can probably help you a lot more.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to give you an answer since you do not provide the function itself. If it is possible to vectorize your calculations, this would be the way to go. Otherwise, you may use `np.vectorize`:

```
import numpy as np

def my_fun(x,y,a,b):
    if x > y:
        return a*x**2 + y
    else:
        return b*x**2 + a*y

vec_fun = np.vectorize(my_fun)
x = np.random.rand(100000)
y = np.random.rand(100000)

%%timeit
for xx,yy in zip(x,y):
    my_fun(xx,yy,1,2)
```

10 loops, best of 3: 138 ms per loop

```
%%timeit
    vec_fun(x,y,1,2)
```

10 loops, best of 3: 65.4 ms per loop

If you just loop over a list of input arguments, you could use `multiprocessing.Pool` in order to utilize all of your cores.

EDIT: As BlackCat noted, the np.vectorize function may not speed up things. If this is the case, the only solution I can think of is either use all cores or switch to Cython.

Comment: thank you for your clear explanation, I will also try what you suggested.

Comment: From the documentation "The `vectorize` function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."  So it isn't what the OP really wants. My results have the loop time as 94.8 ms and the vectorized time as 271 ms, so the version using `vectorize` is actually slower.

Comment: Good point. I forgot that. But the performance difference puzzles me.

Comment: Thank you, actually it worked well in my case, after applying vectorization, the performance time dropped from 61 ms to 5 ms. It seems that it difference depending on the case.

Comment: Did you check your calculations ?

Comment: What I've done is just rewriting the nested loops using np.arange. I didn't try vectorize yet, but I'm interested in using, multiprocessing.Pool. I will check how it will utilize the performance.